# How to Read certain values from a String in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I'm developing an android application where I'm reading results from an online database to a string of this form:

```
{"success":1,"innerResult":[{"username":"raafat","password":"123"}]}
```

I need to be able to read only the username and password values even when I have more than one result. For example i need an array of usernames returned and another array of passwords.

I tried splitting the string but it's confusing when you have many entries.

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON parser...

Comment: it's a `JSON` String...use a JSON parser to parse the String

Comment: this is what you`re looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is in Json format, you can try something like that :

```
try{
    JSONObject yourObject = new JSONObject(yourString);
    int resultCode = yourObject.getInt("success");
    JSONArray innerResult = yourObject.getJSONArray("innerResult");
    //you'll need to iterate through your array then
    List<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> passwords = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0 ; i < innerResult.length() ; i++){
        JSONObject user = innerResult.getJSONObject(i);
        userNames.add(user.getString("username"));
        passwords.add(user.getString("password"));
    }
}catch(JSONException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or you can use library like GSon !

Comment: I still don´t get why you feed code to this monks

Comment: I still don't get why i'm the only one to be criticized

Comment: understand "you" as a plural. In Spanish we say "vosotros". I cannot go repeating comments around without touching the sensibilities of administrators all around. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much Bastien. Maybe my question was trivial but I'm totally new to java and you helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Gson`.

**Step 1:** Creating bean of response data. In your case you want details of `Username` and `Password`.

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Parse JSON response and using `Gson` convert it to your desired bean.

```
String response = "{\"success\":1,\"innerResult\":[{\"username\":\"raafat\",\"password\":\"123\"}]}";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

if(jsonObject.has("innerResult")){
   Type type = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();
   List<User> listUsers = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.getJSONArray("innerResult").toString(), type);
}
```